# flask template jinja not looping as expected

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a flask app with a template inside which I have a loop using jinja syntax. The problem is I don't know why the row[5] is not changing while others are working fine. The  `<p>{{ row[5] }}</p>` is not looping probably in that div nested inside the td tag. The data sent to the page should be looped for 4 times.

{{ row[5] }}

this keeps giving me the value of the first loop. The code is as following:

```
        {% for row in data %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
              <td>{{ row[1] }}</td> 
              <td>{{ row[3] }}</td>
              <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Backup</button>
              <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>{{ row[5] }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              </td>
              <td>Backup</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Even though the data does not matter here. Since someone asked , I will put it here. Data is something like:

```
data=((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

This is the way I render the template:

```
@app.route('/home')
def home(methods=['GET']):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from hosts_custom;")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print data
    return render_template('index.html',data=data)
```

It turns out it's the id and the target stay the same all the time. So when I click on the button it keeps jupping to the myModal target. Thanks everyone for your help!

## Solution

The solution I use is pretty simple.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{ loop.index }}">Backup</button>
                      <div id="myModal{{ loop.index }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

Comment: What do you have in __data__ ?

Comment: @Nabin it's just a tuple inside which there's some infomation like ip, dirs and etc. But it has nothing to do with the data, I tried  to put <td>{{ row[5] }}</td>  alone on the page(not inside the nested tags) , it was working fine.

Comment: Add the data to question, its hard to say like this. Also show what html gets generated for the given data

Comment: @TarunLalwani Actually the data really doesn't matter. But since you asked.I can just suppose the data=[x for x in range(1,10)], so the data is a list contains numbers from 1 to 10. And change all row[x] to just row. Then the <p>{{ row }}</p> stays at 1, others will loop properly, like 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: Can you show the command you have used for render template? Need to see that too. Are you passing a generator by any chance? From your loop it seems you are passing array in data while your approach expected an array of array

Comment: @TarunLalwani Just updated the question. I retrieved the data from database, it's a tuple not a generator.

Comment: Change `data = cursor.fetchall()` to `data = list(cursor.fetchall())` or `data = list(cursor)`. See if that helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani thanks for the suggestion. But listing a tuple doesn't make any difference. I've figured it out. It's the html issue.